# I want to make clay-like animations

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

I want to make a simulation animation like a movie.
I have tried using Fluid in Simulation, but how can I express a viscous substance like clay like in the video?

Or would another method such as Soft Body be better?

Comment: maybe a Displace modifier on subdivided cylinder (+ create some procedural bump)?

Comment: thank you. I will try it and report back.

Comment: did u try metaballs?

Comment: I didn't know about the metaball!
Just thought I'd try it the other way for once!
Thanks for teaching me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help but improve moonboots' answer by using geometry nodes:

[image]

This setup requires Blender 3.3

[image]

Comment: so cool!
I've actually never touched the Geometry node, but I'll give it a try just to see how it looks!
Thank you!

Comment: You must touch it if you want to get into animation. It makes so many types of animation feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try with a *Displace* modifier and *Clouds* texture on a cylinder. I've set the *Coordinates* of the *Displace* to *Object*, and the object is the empty that moves along X or along X + Z if you want the texture to deform like in the gif below. In order to make the clay kind of stick to a tube shape you can push up the *Colors* > *Contrast* and *Brightness* of the clouds texture. Also you can give your clay a bit of bump to create additional relief.

[image]

Comment: ohh thank you so much!!!!
I didn't know there was a way to do this!
I'll try it this way!
Thanks again!