# I want to animate a viscous clay-like object (ball shapes)

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, fluid-simulation

[image]

Actually, I have made [a similar post in the past](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271621/i-want-to-make-clay-like-animations) and I know that I can use geometry nodes but I am ashamed to say that I don't understand geometry nodes, so I don't know the right answer.

I tried to use particles and collision, but it was difficult to make the particles viscous, so I gave up.

Which method should I use to make it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194011/is-there-any-technique-to-give-a-metaball-effect-to-the-particles-emitting-from/194013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried changing texture to Voronoi?

[image]

[image]

If you want ball shapes not to be cut, this is another example:

[image]

You can also make this without Geometry nodes. Just make a particle system:

[image]

Disable gravity:

[image]

Set display as object, with metaball, increase scale to get spheres bigger:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much again!!
I will try both and I will let you know it works or not!